# Use bins/Intervals from pandas qcut to bin another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a pandas dataset1 which needs to be divided into 20 equal parts. So I used pandas qcut (which gives pandas._libs.interval.Interval as bins) to divide it into 20 equal parts. Now I have another dataset called dataset2 which needs to be binned based on the bins/intervals created from dataset1.

Pd.cut (on dataset2) doesn't seem to accept the bins with type pandas._libs.interval.Interval (got from dataset1) but only IntervalIndex. I don't know how to convert "pandas._libs.interval.Interval" to IntervalIndex. Any help with this issue or any other solution to this requirement would be very helpful.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you provide sample data. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example